# Is it possible not be able to access database on an application with sql injection vulnerability?

Tags: sql, database, security, sql-injection

I am pentesting an application for a school paper and i was successful to log in without username and password using 'or'1'='1, but I'm not being able to access the databse though Sqlmap.

I'm using sqlmap -u "application.com" --dbs --threads=10 on Sqlmap and also tried rising --level and --risk.

It is possible that the application is vulnerable to allow the sql injection log in, but immune to the database exploration through Sqlmap, or maybe i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Show us what is running via Sqlmap, and how.

Comment: sqlmap -u "application.com" --dbs --threads=10 also tried rising --level and --risk

Comment: If you are not using prepared statements _and_ your queries take parameters from the outside then you are prone to SQL injection.

Comment: it's a black box pentest. i have no access to the application code

Comment: How about logging in with `'; DELETE FROM users`?  If the API supports multiple statements in a single query, then there might be a way to do other attacks via the login point.

Comment: i'll test it, ty for the tip. so do you think it is possible that the application is vulnerable to this kind of sql injection exploit, but it's immune to explore the tables via sqlmap? i need to answer this question

Comment: Again, if you can pass in outside parameters via SQLmap, then it is also maybe vulnerable.

Comment: It would depend on how the app was passing the input field. Not all sql statements are likely to result in valid syntax so might fail if a hacker tries to inject something else. And its very often not going to allow the return of data if the results don't look like the app is expecting, siuch as your sqlmap commend.I would say that a simple hack such as you have done where you are adding something inside a where clause is much more likely to work, which of course is bad enough. A command that doesnt return anything such as the one Tim suggested might also work.